# Call store Switcher in phtml file directly in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2.2, phtml

I want to call Store Switcher in  phtml file directly.
I tried to call directly but its not working.
Kindly review.

```
       $this->getLayout()
      ->createBlock('Magento\Store\Block\Switcher')
      ->setTemplate('store_switcher::switch/stores.phtml')
      ->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()
      ->createBlock('Magento\Store\Block\Switcher')
      ->setTemplate('Magento_Store::switch/stores.phtml')
      ->toHtml(); ?>
```

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Thanks, Its working.

Comment: what is Magento_Store in the line 'Magento_Store::switch/stores.phtml

Comment: Magento_Store is default Magento module which is available here.. **vendor/magento/module-store** and we are accessing template file from that directory. **vendor/magento/module-store/view/frontend/templates/switch/stores.phtml**

Comment: @KishanSavaliya I have called in the .phtml file but it's not working any other solution?

Comment: @SavanDholu what error you're getting?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya No, any error showing.